# How to Abort Git Bisect

Tags: git, abort, git-bisect

I started my git bisect by specifying good and bad revisions but I don't think they registered. Additionally, as I am attempting to specify git bisect good and bad, I don't think git is doing anything. I would like to abort the entire bisect so that I can re-initiate the operation. `git bisect reset` seems to be what I am looking for, but I want to double check before potentially messing anything up.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

`git bisect reset` is the correct command. From [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html):

> After a bisect session, to clean up the bisection state and return to the original HEAD, issue the following command:
>
> ```
> $ git bisect reset
> ```
>
> By default, this will return your tree to the commit that was checked out before `git bisect start`. (A new `git bisect start` will also do that, as it cleans up the old bisection state.)

Comment: Grrr, that's not an intuitive name compared to the other git commands... I was hoping for a `git bisect abort`

Comment: @JasonAxelson unfortunately, you have been eaten alive by the git hobgoblin https://stevelosh.com/blog/2013/04/git-koans/#s4-the-hobgoblin